# remove multiple-background tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The [multiple-background](/questions/tagged/multiple-background)tag has no wiki/summary. It has 0 followers. It is grammatically flawed (shouldn't it be multiple-backgrounds?) It is used on less than 50 questions, and I couldn't find an example where it seemed useful. It is generally used in conjunction with a title that says "I want to have multiple backgrounds". Most of the questions relate to CSS, but it is not clear that this is its intended use. I feel like people only add this tag when they are using the type-ahead feature and start typing "multiple", and it appears to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to merge and synonymize this into the [background-image](/questions/tagged/background-image) tag, which should perfectly well cover the use of multiple background images, as per its tag wiki excerpt:

> The background-image CSS property sets one or more background images for an element.

The only difference between CSS2.1 and CSS3 is that you can add a comma and define a second (and third, fourth, etc) background. The use of a comma in the property doesn't really warrant a second tag. It's all the same rules, all the same knowledge, just applied multiple times.

If a user wants to specifically reference the CSS3 background-image property, they can tag it both [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) and [background-image](/questions/tagged/background-image).

Comment: Thanks, I think your solution makes more sense than removing it. I wasn't aware of the background-image tag.